# Removing Files When Uninstalling via InstallShield Limited

Tags: c++, installation, installshield, uninstallation

I created an installer using InstallSheild Limited. During the install process, I have a Custom Action which runs a C++ exe after registering the product. In the C++ exe, I move files that are in the installers program directory to various places on the computer.

Now, I need to make the uninstaller be able to remove those files. Is there a way to do this in InstallSheild Limited Edition. If not, what can I do to achieve the same results?

Comment: An uninstall custom action? By the way, if you have removed the original files when you moved them to various places on the computer, see what happens of you do a repair on your product - it will most likely want to reinstall them.

Comment: @PhilDW Yes I noticed that with the repair. I did use the custom action. However, I can only do custom actions after the computer has changed. So, when I try to access the files that were moved into the program files folder, by the time the custom action runs, that folder does not exist anymore.